# How to balancing sample sizes across groups in r？

Tags: r

I have a set of data, the original data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZhUgrXZ2iRG8LrysMSV19I5LWkJz1OjI/view
I wanted to make a heat map to show the changing trend of BMI, but I found that the amount of data between each group was too different, as shown in the figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0j9X.png)

The first and last groups with the largest amount of data have more than 300 data, and the smallest group has only two data.
Is there any function in R that can balance the amount of data in each group after trade-offs? I hope it is 30 data in each group.

Sorry, I don't know how to try other code other than keep grouping them.
Hope to get some suggestions or help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about what you are hoping to show?

Something like this shows a trend in BMI relative to `Hypocretin.level`

```
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
BMI_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Hypocretin.level), y = BMI)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Crikey,I want to find a way to get the sample size to be 30 for each Hypocretin group. I tried using Smote, but I got error: new_df <- smote(Hypocretin.level ~ ., BMI_data, perc.over = 100, perc.under = 200)
Error in factor(newCases[[a]], levels = 1:nlevels(data[[a]]), labels = levels(data[[a]])) :
'labels' is wrong; length 0 should be one or 2
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them).                                         
I have no idea about that. Could you give me some suggestions?